# C# initialize list property

Tags: c#, list, properties

Am having below classes...how do i initialise with some values
        My question is, how do i initialise above RootObject with some values in Main
        For example

```
    Rootobject robj = new Rootobject();
    robj.inchistor.Add()     



    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace JsonSample3
    {

        public class Customerinfo
        {
            public string customername { get; set; }
            public string address { get; set; }
            public string postcode { get; set; }
        }

        public class Inchistory
        {

            public Customerinfo customerinfo { get; set; }
            public string r { get; set; }
            public string reference { get; set; }
            public string region { get; set; }

        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Inchistory> inchistory { get; set; }
        }


    }

    class Program
    {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
               RootObject robj = new RootObject{ r = "", }

            }
    }



   Am having above classes namely CustomerInfo, Inchistory and Rootobject
```

Answer (score 16):

The default value for any reference type is `null`.  So I assume you're getting a `NullReferenceException` when you try to add values.  You can initialize your list property to an empty list in the object's constructor:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Inchistory> inchistory { get; set; }

    public RootObject()
    {
        inchistory = new List<Inchistory>();
    }
}
```

Now any instance of `RootObject` will have a valid (empty) list by default, allowing you to add to it:

```
Rootobject robj = new Rootobject();
robj.inchistor.Add(someInstanceOfInchistory);
```

Comment: The collection property shouldn't have any setter if possible, which would make it impossible for this collection to be ever be null. .NET Serialization would still work since it uses AddRange<T>(IEnumerable<T>) instead of new List<T>(IEnumerable<T>).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking. Are you looking for a combination of object and collection initialization?

```
RootObject robj = new RootObject() 
{
    inchistory = new List<Inchistory>() 
    {
       new Inchistory() 
       {
           r = "foo",
           reference = "bar",
           customerinfo = new CustomerInfo()
           {
                customername = "joe blogs",
                address = "somewhere",
                postcode = "xxx xxxx"
           },
           region = "somewhere"
       },
       new Inchistory()
       {
           // etc
       }
    }
};
```

Or if you don't have things to add right now, you can just do:

```
RootObject robj = new RootObject() 
{
    inchistory = new List<Inchistory>() 
};
```

Or you could actually initialize the list inside the class constructor as David suggested.