# C# Add List/Lists to Data Class instance

Tags: c#

Very new to C# and I'm trying to create a list of node data which contains a variable list length of Link data.

```
  class Data
{
    public List<Node> Node { get; set; }
}

public class Node
{
    public string viewer { get; set; }
    public int viewerId { get; set; }
    public string log { get; set; }
    public List <Link> Link { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string keyName { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
```

}

i have a for loop iterating through the configured nodes and an inner for loop
to grab any configured links.

```
Data data = new Data();
data.Node = new List<Node>();
```

I'm doing the following for each new node, which is working how i want it.

```
 data.Node.Add( new Node {
                    viewer = setup.Device[moduleNr].viewer,
                    viewerId = setup.Device[moduleNr].viewerId ,
                    log = setup.Device[moduleNr].log
                    // how to add one or more lists of Link to this list???                       
                });
```

The problem i'm having is adding a new list/lists inside the existing data.Node???

Ultimately i would like to achieve the following -

```
data
|->Node
       |->[0]
           |->Link
                 |->[0]
                     |->keyname
                     |->value
                 |->[1]
                     |->keyname
                     |->value
                 |->[2]
                     |->keyname
                     |->value
           |->log
           |->viewerId
           |->viewer

    |->[1]
           |->Link
                 |->[0]
                     |->keyname
                     |->value
                 |->[1]
                     |->keyname
                     |->value

           |->log
           |->viewerId
           |->viewer
        |->[2]
           |->Link
                 |->[0]
                     |->keyname
                     |->value
           |->log
           |->viewerId
           |->viewer
```

Would really appreciate some help with this issue - Thanks

Comment: Normally you know the node you're adding to and instead of data.node you use nodewhatever ..

Comment: something like `new Node { theproperties..., Link = new List<Link> { link1, link2 ... }}` See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919818/c-sharp-initialize-list-property for adding items to your list on initialization.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837063/cast-object-to-generic-list

Comment: As a sidenote, can I recommend you rename the list Node to Nodes, and the list Link to Links.  This is convention and improves readability.
Also have you thought about using a dictionary for the links, seeing as they contain a keyname, value pair?

Comment: "how to add one or more lists of Link to this list" I guess you mean : **how to add one or more Link elements to the list called Link ?=! Is that correct?

Comment: @Unknown_Coder. That doesn't appear to be relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new instance of a `List<Link>` like this and use the constructor to add new items:

```
data.Node.Add(new Node {
                  viewer = setup.Device[moduleNr].viewer,
                  viewerId = setup.Device[moduleNr].viewerId ,
                  log = setup.Device[moduleNr].log,
                  Link = new List<Link>
                  {
                      new Link
                      {
                          keyName = "Link 1",
                          value = 0
                      },
                      new Link
                      {
                          keyName = "Link 2",
                          value = 1
                      }
                  }     
              });
```